# Redirection based on variables assigned within while loop setup

Tags: shell, while-loop, do-while

I want to access while loop variable out side the loop

```
while read line
do
...
...
...
done < $file > /home/Logs/Sample_$line_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log
```

In the above example whatever the log file is getting generated that doesn't have the value for the line variable. i.e. $line is not working here.

Please let me know how this can be written to make it work.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 1> /home/Logs/`basename $0 | cut -d"." -f1 | sed 's/\.sh//g'`_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log 2>&1
echo "Execution Started : `date` \n"
SQL_DIR=/home/Sql
INFILE=in_file
TEMPFILE=temp_file
RETURN_CODE=0
ls -ltr $SQL_DIR|grep ".sql"|awk -F" " '{print $9}'|awk -F"." '{print $1}' > $INFILE
sed '/^$/d' $INFILE > $TEMPFILE; mv $TEMPFILE $INFILE

while read line
do
      {
        START_TIME=`date +%s`

        printf "\n SQL File Executed Is : $line.sql"
        SQL_FILE_NM=$line.sql
        SQL_FILE=$SQL_DIR/$SQL_FILE_NM
        nzsql -db netezza_db -Atqf $SQL_FILE > /dev/null

        RETURN_CODE=$?
        if [ $RETURN_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Time taken to execute sqlfile $SQL_FILE=$TT_HRS:$TT_MINS:$TT_REM_SECS HH:MM:SS" > $TEMPFILE
                printf "\n Success: Sql completed successfully at `date` \n"
                cat $TEMPFILE|mailx -s "Time taken to execute sqlfile $SQL_FILE=$TT_HRS:$TT_MINS:$TT_REM_SECS HH:MM:SS" 'koushik.chandra@a.com'
        else
                printf "\n Error: Failed in sql execution at `date`"
                exit $RETURN_CODE
        fi

        END_TIME=`date +%s`
        TT_SECS=$(( END_TIME - START_TIME))
        TT_HRS=$(( TT_SECS / 3600 ))
        TT_REM_MS=$(( TT_SECS % 3600 ))
        TT_MINS=$(( TT_REM_MS / 60 ))
        TT_REM_SECS=$(( TT_REM_MS % 60 ))
        printf "\n"
        printf "Total time taken to execute the sql $line="$TT_HRS:$TT_MINS:$TT_REM_SECS HH:MM:SS
        printf "\n"
      } > /home/Logs/sql_query_time_$line_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log

done < $INFILE

rm -f $INFILE $TEMPFILE
exit $RETURN_CODE
```

Comment: This is odd.. `line` variable will be changing for every line of input file.

Comment: Yes ... If I have 3 lines in the file. then I want to generate 3 log files and log file name should contain processing file detail.

Comment: As per my understanding while executes in sub-shell, but if we can execute it in current shell then probably this can be achieved. How can we execute while in current shell?

Comment: Oh  .. it works after putting line variable within braces  as below : `/home/Logs/sql_query_time_$**{**line**}**_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log`

Comment: FYI, this is what "code sample", not "code snippet" functionality is for. "Code snippets" are for things that can be run inside the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need redirection inside the while loop:

```
while read -r line; do
   { cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; } > "/home/Logs/Sample_${line}_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log"
done < "$file"
```

When you have `> outfile` after `done` then output is redirected to one file only.

Comment: I am executing several commands in side the while loop and I don't want to add this re-direction after every command

Comment: No. With this approach still it is not taking the value of the line variable.

Comment: That's not true. Value of `line` is available. Show your script in question.

Comment: Provided the whole script in the original post. Just modified mail-id. The idea is to find time taking by long running queries, without capturing the output of the queries. SQL queries are saved in SQL_DIR

Comment: You didn't follow and command I provided. Note how I am using **`"/home/Logs/Sample_${line}_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log"`** but you have `/home/Logs/sql_query_time_$line_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log`

Comment: Yes  .. it works after putting line variable within braces  as below : `/home/Logs/sql_query_time_${line}_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log`..what is the difference of braces here

Comment: @KoushikChandra, without the braces the `_` is taken as part of the variable name.

Comment: Thanks anubhava and Charles Duffy